# What does mean the ElasticSearch exceptions: "all shards failed" and "No search context found for id"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with ELS using the Scroll API and the following errors is persisting:

```
 09:21:12.118] elastic-qlik-event-job [main] ERROR com.valemobi.ImportExportController - Não foi possivel recuperar pagina: 
    org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1793)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1770)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1527)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1484)
        at 
        Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://database.elasticsearch.*.prod:8088], URI [/_search/scroll], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id [15068451]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":-1,"index":null,"reason":{"type":"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id [15068451]"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id [15068451]"}},"status":404}
            at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:283)
            at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:261)
            at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:235)
            at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1514)
            ... 15 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_context_missing_exception, reason=No search context found for id [15068451]]
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:496)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:407)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:437)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.failureFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:603)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:169)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Does anybody have any idea what may be causing this and how do I fix it?